# INSERT INTO CASE EXEC SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

When I execute this statement I get an error around CASE. 
How can I change it to execute a SP on when certain conditions are true. The conditions will be variables

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(
Col 1
Col 2
)

CASE
WHEN Condition 1 AND Condition 2 THEN
Exec SP1
WHEN Condition 3 AND Condition 4 THEN
Exec SP2
END
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try it? Does it work? "Is it possible?" isn't really a meaningful question. "Is it possible that the sun will rise tomorrow?" could be answered yes, but there's also a very miniscule chance that it won't. Please [edit] to ask a more specific question, such as "When I try (this statement), it fails with the error ..." or "When I execute (this statement), the output isn't what I'd expect. I expect (this) but get (this instead)". Vague questions about whether something is possible or not can be answered by "Yes, it is", "No, it isn't", or "Maybe", all of which can be true.

Comment: Again, **be more specific**. In what way doesn't it work? Do you get an error? If so, what is the exact error message? You know what "doesn't work" means - [edit] your post and include that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'INSERT INTO myTable
            (Col1,  Col2) '
          + CASE
              WHEN Condition 1 AND Condition 2 THEN
                N'Exec SP1'
              WHEN Condition 3 AND Condition 4 THEN
                N'Exec SP2'
            END  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

Also if your stored procedures take any parameters you can add them as follow:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'INSERT INTO myTable
            (Col1,  Col2) '
          + CASE
              WHEN Condition 1 AND Condition 2 THEN
                N'Exec SP1 @Param1'
              WHEN Condition 3 AND Condition 4 THEN
                N'Exec SP2 @Param2'
            END  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@Param1 DataType, @Param2 DataType'
                     ,@Param1 ,@Param2
```

Comment: And the reason this is the correct answer is because [The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Thats why I haven't tried to control the execution flow, but just simply built the query 1st and executed it :)

Comment: You're answer is outstanding. My additional explanation was meant for the OP, so he would understand why his attempt did not work and why you had to use `sp_executesql`. It seemed to make more sense in the context of your answer.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation it is really helpful for any reading this answer :).

Answer (score 0):

No, that wont work because the insert statement expects to find a set of data that matches the columns when doing the actual inserting.

You would be better off calling a single SP, and having an if statement inside it to perform your conditional branching OR have the conditions call the SP's as you have, but have the entire insert statement inside the SP's.